# Restricting ssh and ftp access to unix server

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I know I can restrict ssh and ftp access to my unix server by using tools like ufw (uncomplicated firewall). What if I restrict ssh and ftp access to one IP address (my home IP) and then suddenly lose access to my home IP, before I get a chance to update the ufw conf? Is there a way I can get into the server without having to wipeout my instance and do everything from scratch? I use a VPS instance that runs ubuntu if it matters.

Comment: use the VPS portal?

Comment: @shroeder this should be an answer ...